# Can I create view with di-container in custom TriggerAction in WPF and Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

For an example,
I want to develop a PopupWindowAction which can popup custom window.

```
        <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding OpenMyCutomDialog}">
            <prism:PopupMyCutomDialogAction IsModal="True">
            </prism:PopupMyCutomDialogAction>
        </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

MyCutomDialogView is a Window, but it has some constructor params. I think it should be a good practice to use di-container to create it.

```
public class PopupMyCutomDialogAction : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        // how to access container and create MyCutomDialog?
    }
}
```

How to create MyCutomDialog by using di-container?
(In this case, we only use global variable to access di-container in PopupMyCutomDialogAction?)

Very thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the DI container to resolve objects in your custom trigger action you can use the ServiceLocator to do it;

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyServie>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I heared some one said "ServiceLocator is an anti-pattern". Whether there are other solutions?

Comment: I agree it's an anti-pattern if you can use constructor injection instead. Sometimes that's not possible and then the ServiceLocator is a great solution. You can misuse/abuse every pattern.